# Rectangles have different size but their properties are the same

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml, qtquick2

There are two lines made by `Rectangle`:

```
// Horizontal line
Rectangle {
        // ...
        width:  parent.width * 0.26   // line length
        height: lineWidth             // line width
        // ...
}

// Vertical line
Rectangle {
        // ..
        width:  lineWidth // line width
        height: parent.height * 0.56 // line length
        // ..
}
```

`lineWidth` is a property and it is the same for all lines.

```
readonly property real lineWidth: height * 0.0035 
// 'height' is the height of the window
```

A window 800x600 looks good - all lines have the same width. But when I resize window, they don't look the same, although their properties are the same (log from console):

```
qml: Vertical line: 2.1
qml: Horizontal line: 2.1
qml: Vertical line: 2.1035
qml: Horizontal line: 2.1035
qml: Vertical line: 2.107
qml: Horizontal line: 2.107
qml: Vertical line: 2.1105
qml: Horizontal line: 2.1105
qml: Vertical line: 2.114
qml: Horizontal line: 2.114
qml: Vertical line: 2.1175
qml: Horizontal line: 2.1175
qml: Vertical line: 2.121
qml: Horizontal line: 2.121
....
```

[image: Comparison between 800x600 and 1365x717]

In addition, there's difference not only in vertical and horizontal lines. Parallel lines (both vertical and horizontal) have the difference too.

Could you please explain me what's wrong?

Comment: round-off error? What are the positions?

Comment: @derM, yup, you directed me to the answer. I had rounded the lineWidth by Math.round() and the problem was solved. You can post the answer.